# Using Ordering on Instant

Tags: java, scala

Is there Ordering which I can use to Order `Instant`?

I'm currently using the following Ordering:

```
MyRuleEngine(Equals).eval(Instant.now(), Instant.now().plusSeconds(1))(Ordering.by(_.toEpochMilli)) shouldBe false
```

But its might throw Exception (`@throws ArithmeticException if numeric overflow occurs`) - any other suggestings?
I want to order based on the time-line position of the instants

Im using the following function:

```
 def eval[T](checkedValue: T, checkedWithValue: T)(ord: Ordering[T]) : Boolean
```

I'm looking for a solution as follows:

```
MyRuleEngine(GreaterThan).eval("B", "A")(scala.math.Ordering.String) shouldBe true
MyRuleEngine(GreaterThan).eval(10, 0)(scala.math.Ordering.Int) shouldBe true
MyRuleEngine(Equals).eval(true, true)(scala.math.Ordering.Boolean) shouldBe true
```

Using `2.12.8`

Comment: The idea of a **Typeclass** like `Ordering` is that you do not pass it explicitly. In any case, at least on `2.13` there is an instance of `Ordering` for `Instant` out of the box in the stdlib.

Comment: I just checked using that version and again I can find the same out of the box instance. - Check [this](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/BalmungSan/etwDMC3OREKsNLtLzWbOHA/2) :)

Comment: Thanks @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez - I cannot use it with `scala.math.LowPriorityOrderingImplicits` - Its cannot find it for some reason

Comment: What do you mean you can not find it? Again, you should not use its explicit name juts ask for it implicitly by type. - did you read the links I shared yesterday? It would be good for you to become familiar with the **typeclass** pattern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unlike `Ordering[String]` or `Ordering[Int]`, Scala doesn't have an explicit `val` or `object` with `Ordering[Instant]`. Scala compiler generates one on demand when you  implicitly request it by relying on the fact that `Instant` extends `Comparable` in Java.

If you want to use the `Ordering[Instant]` provided by Scala, you have to summon the implicit one and have the compiler generate it for you:

```
MyRuleEngine(rule).eval(instant1, instant2)(Ordering[Instant])
```

or

```
MyRuleEngine(rule).eval(instant1, instant2)(implicitly)
```

You may also manually create an `Ordering[Instant]` in the same way the compiler does:

```
MyRuleEngine(rule).eval(instant1, instant2)(Ordering.ordered(identity))
```

Comment: It really doesn't make much sense to pass a **typeclass** like `Ordering` explicitly, specially in the entry point of your API.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez I think OP is deserializing all the data from external sources and doesn't know much about static types. So at some at point he has to `match` on the actual runtime type he received to summon and store the correct `Ordering` for it. And then it doesn't really matter if that ordering is passed explicitly or implicitly, and maybe passing explicitly makes the code easier to follow.

Comment: I can agree with passing it explicitly inside your internal code, but not really on your entry point, it kind of breaks the point of a typeclass. - Yeah, if OP is reading some serialized date, I believe the best he / she could do would be deserializing it into a sealed **ADT** of all the possible cases to recover static typing ASAP and then he / she would only need one single and safe pattern match.

Answer (score 0):

You can summon just the standard implicit `Ordering[Instant]` by:

```
implicit val instantOrdering: Ordering[Instant] = Ordering[Instant]
```

This will call the `apply` method on `Ordering` which summons the instance which is derived in the `LowPriorityOrderingImplicits` trait (which the `Ordering` companion object extends) from the fact that `Instant` extends `java.lang.Comparable[Instant]`.

You can directly derive the `Ordering` instance for `Instant` with:

```
val instantOrdering = Ordering.ordered[Instant]
```

`Ordering.ordered` will work for any type `T` which extends `Comparable[T]`.

You can also define a functionally equivalent instance with

```
val instantOrdering: Ordering[Instant] = Ordering.fromLessThan[Instant] { (x, y) => x.isBefore(y) }
```

Comment: Thanks @LeviRamsey! - I guess that scala already implemented it somewhere, and i want to use their implementation instead of writing my own one - check `I'm looking for a solution as follows`.